# WebCamera with C#

Tags: c#, camera

Hello and thanks always for your help
This time I would like to ask about how to capture an image (from a USB camera) using C#.
I have googled about this and so far I found two examples (plus one that I have in a book here but that is not working) in which they require three layers.

The top layer is the application layer in which the developer writes his code
The medium layer is a C# wrapper of...
The lower layer which is usually implemented as a DLL and is always done in C++. This is the layer that makes calls to DirectShow.

Now, is this how this should be done?? C# can not handle a web camera directly?

An example of what I found is 
[Yet another web camera control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/330177/Yet-another-Web-Camera-control)

(Please note that this time I am not able to use OpenCV or libraries like that. In fact I have already developed one program that streams a web camera and captures screenshots using OpenCV some time ago)

Any other comment or advice will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I myself used [AForge.NET framework](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/downloads.html) it's free and it works very easy.
For audio capture, I used [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/).
You can you can easily install them with NuGet package manager Console.

Aforge Install-Package AForge

NAudio Install-Package NAudio